# Cannot run any unit tests in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, .net-framework-version

I have recently downloaded Visual Studio 2015 and imported an old project into it.
The problem is that now none of the unit tests run, and instead I get the dreaded BadImageFormatException

```
Unable to get type GameTests.UnitTest1. Error: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\...\bin\Debug\GameTests.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
File name: 'file:///C:\Users\...\bin\Debug\GameTests.dll'
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TypeCache.LoadType(String typeName, String assemblyName)
```

At first I thought that there might have been something wrong when I transferred an existing project to VS2015, but I have tried with a newly created project, and the same happens. I have also tried both MS UnitTestFramework and NUnit. Nothing seems to help.

Any ideas?

P.S. - I've also set the Platform target to x86 and checked that all my projects have the same target framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [changing your app config](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shitals/2012/04/23/badimageformatexception-this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded/)?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it in my Class Library project but my test project does not have an app.config file of course

  `<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>`

Comment: You can add an App.config to it. Even copy from the library

Comment: That doesn't seem to help either

Comment: What is the target runtime of the GameTests project?

Comment: Both projects are set to 4.5.2

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that your bin folder contains old DLLs, if you delete then it might work

Comment: I have also tried that with no success. I am a bit confused because this is also happening with newly created projects with no external references

Comment: Following your last suggestion, I uninstalled VS and re-installed it again, and now I can finally run the tests again :D

Comment: Great! Probably something wrong with the installation - you should report it to Microsoft